# How can I start my gmail add-on automatically when the user opens an e-mail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I am trying to build a gmail add-on which starts automatically when the user opens an email and display them some information. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Chrome extension you can use to automatically open any add-on from Gmail, Calendar, Drive and Docs when you open the corresponding web page.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-open-add-on/bcjnialkobgkdkbdclhdnbdcdgdcgdlo

Answer (score 0):

I opened a feature request to have Google Workspace Add-ons open after user install. https://issuetracker.google.com/300311520

Answer (score -1):

You could start with this document https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-gsuite-addons

1. you need a script project and standalone script
2. In Gmail app, there are 3 triggers, homepage trigger (when the user is at homepage), contextual trigger (when the user is reading an email) and compose trigger (when user composing an email), you could declare the triggers on add-on manifest file
3. create handler as CB function for these triggers and declare them on the manifest file
4. you could easily install the add-on by Publish -> deploy from manifest -> install add-on (on your Gmail account)

I extremely suggest read the doc, as there is amazing documentation, how to developing G suite add-on

Comment: this appear to be only callbacks for when the icon to open the add-on is clicked. I want the add-on side bar to open automatically without having to click, on an event such as when an email is opened

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77100528/3145360 See my answer for the feature request to enable this.